# Which protocols (TCP or UDP) consume more %CPU?

Tags: linux, tcp, cpu-usage, udp

I'm sending data from the client to server using IPERF3, fist I used TCP and then UDP. I observed that maximum time TCP consumed more %cpu than UDP. Generally which one suppose to consumed more %CPU? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be **TCP** because of Dynamic Header, Checksum and Flow control mechanisms.

Comment: One more - in the common packet investigation graph UDP check stays before TCP one.

Answer (score 4):

TCP is way more complex than UDP, so it will be more resource-consuming. To name some differences, TCP guarantees that no packets will be lost in transit and that payload will be reconstructed properly, even if packets arrive out-of-order.

Quality network adapters for PCs have dedicated hardware that can offload this task from CPU. This is not the case for cheap (and common) Realtek NICs.

Comment: Can you please say little more details? thanks for your answer.

Comment: What kind of details would you like me to add?

Comment: @gronostaj sorry, I'm not cleared about the last paragraph. Thanks.

Comment: @Humayun_kabir Good quality network adapters can do TCP computations themselves, without putting much load on the CPU. Network adapters manufactured by Realtek are built to be cheap and affordable, so they don't have built-in TCP capabilities. Instead, network drivers use computer's CPU to run TCP. This may cause high CPU usage when downloading/uploading with high speed.